# How to replace whole table

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I need to create database that should represent currently available torrents on torrent tracker and update it completely every day or so, replacing previously saved data and erasing records about those torrents which were deleted from the site.

How can I do it? If I just collect new data in the temporary table and then try to do `DROP TABLE` and rename temporary table to the main table's name, I'll make other resources which also use this DB unable to do their work for some period of time. Or this is the best way to do it anyway and I should just do these operations in one transaction?

I'm going to use MySQL or PostgreSQL, but I can change this idea to the one you'll give me reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL `truncate table` followed by insert statement(s). https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: So, `TRUNCATE TABLE` and a lot of `INSERT` statements in one and possibly huge transaction?

Comment: To limit the number of insert statements you can use `batch insert` (not sure if this is the correct name.) Anyway, the documentation says it is fast.